# Get field and values from firebase flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How will i be able to retrieve the field and field values from firebase?

i want to retrieve "total payment" and its value and store it in array. Below is my code for getting the field values but not the field names.

```
Future _getDataFromDatabase() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("payments").doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).get().then((snapshot)async{
      if(snapshot.exists){
        setState((){
          totalPayments = snapshot.data()!["total payment"].toString();
          balance = snapshot.data()!["remaining balance"].toString();
          print(totalPayments);     
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify how you want the array to look like?

Comment: inside the get data function, data = ["total payment","20,500.59","remaining balance","5,570.59"] - stored in an array. I wanted field name to be included in the array instead of just the field value.

Answer (score 2):

snapshot is of type Map<String, dynamic> so if I understand your question correctly you are asking how to cast a map into a list with its keys preserved as string values.

you can get a list of a key-value pairs using something like

```
IterableZip([snapshot.keys, snapshot.values])
```

and then you can flatten it into a list using any approach but the shortest would be using `expand`
so the final code would be:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
//... after that you can use
IterableZip([snapshot.keys, snapshot.values]).expand((i) => i).toList()
```

Comment: yes  i want get the keys and its values then store it in an array